# how to not fire a submit button on change event

Tags: jquery

I have a button and i have a menu. I want if the menu switched from 5 to 2, I want the button to not fire. I do not want to use disable..I just want it to not fire.

So if user switches the menu to 5 and then decide to go back to #1 a way for that button to not fire.

The button should fire only when the user is on any other part of the menu except when it moves from 5 to #2. It can move from 5 to #3 or 5 to 0 but not #5 to 2.

```
 <select id="mOne">
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
<option>three</option>
 <option>four</option>
 <option>five</option>
 </select>
 <br></br>
 <br></br>
 <input type="button" id="startOver" value="Start Over"></input>

$("#mOne").on("change", function () {
if ($(this).val() === "0") {

} else if ($(this).val() === "1") {


} else if ($(this).val() === "2") {

});

$("#startOver").click(function () {
alert("button fired");
});

$("#answerButton").click(function () {
alert("pressed");

 });
```

Comment: Just use `unbind` http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: or use `one()`. Not 100% clear when code should fire ... description of behavior not very concise. Also doesn't sound very user friendly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you are wanting, although it's still a little unclear what expectations are.

It stores the last value on the element itself  using `data()`

```
$("#mOne").on("change", function () {
    var $self = $(this),
        currVal = $self.val(),
        lastVal = $self.data('lastVal');
    if (lastVal == 5 && currVal == 1) {
        alert('not allowed');
    } else {
        $self.data('lastVal', currVal);
        /* do something else here */
    }

}).data('lastVal', -1);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/83hyprsj/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Theres a button that also supposed to be on the screen with the menu. The button is allowed to fire all the time unless the user moves from 5 to 2, then the button can no longer fire.

Comment: Still not clear what button and select relationship is though

Comment: almost!….how do i get that alert that is saying invalid to not alert at all? I need it to not do anything.

Comment: just remove the alert. i only put them there for testing it

Comment: but what if i had code on the button to do something? I see the else..ill put the code there. Thanks